# Tzlach - source of name?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, names

The Noda BiYehuda has a commentary on Shas known as Tzlach - can someone help me by explaining what that stands for?

Comment: Are you sure the Tzlach doesn't have a book of responsa known as Noda BiYehuda? Just kidding. The Dagul Mer'vava wrote both!

Answer (score 8):

In his [introduction](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37718&st=&pgnum=2), the Noda Biyehudah says that indeed the sefer was named for his mother (as Shalom mentioned in his comment). He also adds that the ל in לנפש represents his father (since יהודה equals 30, same as ל), and that the word ציון is for his own name, since it has the same gematria as יחזקאל.

Answer (score 6):

ציון לנפש חיה = צל"ח

Comment: _Tziyun_, not _tziyon_.

Comment: That's what he said. :)

Answer (score 3):

[ציון לנפש חיה](http://hebrewbooks.org/24669)

The abbreviation also has the connotation of "success" (צלח is the imperative form of הצלחה.) I'm not sure whether that meaning was intended, though.

Comment: "Tziun l'nefesh chaya" means: "a signpost for a living soul." Rabbi Yechezkel Landau dedicated the book to his mother's memory, whose name was Chaya. (Just as his responsa, Noda BiHuda ("known in Judah") was dedicated to the memory of his father, Yehudah.)

Comment: Just two small additions to R'Shalom's comment: One, _tziyun_ is also a word used to mean "grave marker". Two, _tziyun l'nefesh chaya_ can also be read as "a [ _tziyun_ ] for Chaya's soul"; I guess the double entendre was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a quote from the posuk ‘tzlach rchav al Dvar emes" psalms 45:5